# How to find out sparkR master site?

Tags: r

I installed sparkR standalone and ran it. I did get the spark context but i am unable to find the master site (localhost:8080) does not work for me. Are there any separate command to launch master site ?

```
Loading required package: SparkR
[SparkR] Initializing with classpath         
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/SparkR/lib/SparkR/sparkr-assembly-0.1.jar

Launching java with command  java   -Xmx512m -cp 
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/SparkR/lib/SparkR/
sparkr-assembly-0.1.jar:' edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.SparkRBackend    
/var/folders/ln/tcj6cdjd6ss5bq460m7rxwh8fq9k4s/T//RtmpQXn4Wb/backend_portd35957a1c484 
15/03/25 01:18:02 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started

 Welcome to SparkR!
 Spark context is available as sc
 >
```

Answer (score 2):

SparkR by default runs with Spark master set as "local". In that case there is no master UI, but you should be able to see the application UI at localhost:4040.